# Explanation for unintended output from Ti-83Plus?

Tags: basic, texas-instruments, ti-basic

```
Output(1,1,"v=v0+at") 

Output(2,1,"deltax=v0t+1/2at") 

Output(4,1,"v^2=v0^2+2deltax") 

Output(5,1,"deltax=1/2(v0+v)t") 

Output(6,1,"vt-1/2at^2")
```

I use a cable to transfer programs.

Above code works perfectly fine besides the first line where it outputs `v=v0+atMU`. If I move the last 3 outputs by one row it becomes MS.

Was wondering if someone can explain why?

Comment: Is there text already on the screen when you're executing the program? If so, you might have to add `ClrHome` at the start of your program to clear the screen first.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there must be something happening behind the printed text. Could the name of the program end in MU? And the one where you shift the last three in MS? It might become clear if you move all of the outputs by one row.